# Use a Macro on a list of information. New worksheet needed for each row of information

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I'm new to all this Macro thing and haven't used before, so could do with a bit of help.

I've set up a Macro to create a new Quote from a template and list of information. I have a sheet named Summery which includes customer information etc and all of this info is needed to be added to the quote template. I have created a basic Macro and it does the job but I now need it to do the same for each customer listed. At the moment it only runs on the first row. 
Please can someone assist in what code I need to use for it to run on the entire list of customers?

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
' Create New Quote for each customer
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q

    Sheets("Master").Select
    Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(2)
    Range("A13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-9]C[1]"
    Range("A15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-11]C[2]"
    Range("E13").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-9]C[-1]"
    Range("E15").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-11]C"
    Range("B19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-15]C[5]"
    Range("B20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-16]C[6]"
    Range("B21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-17]C[7]"
    Range("B22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-18]C[8]"
    Range("B23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-19]C[9]"
    Range("B24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-20]C[10]"
    Range("B25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-21]C[11]"
    Range("B26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-22]C[12]"
    Range("B27").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-23]C[13]"
    Range("B28").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-24]C[14]"
    Range("B30").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-26]C[15]"
    Range("B31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-27]C[16]"
    Range("B32").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-28]C[17]"
    Range("B33").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-29]C[18]"
    Range("B34").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-30]C[19]"
    Range("B35").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-31]C[20]"
    Range("B36").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-32]C[21]"
    Range("B37").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-33]C[22]"
    Range("B38").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-34]C[23]"
    Range("B39").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-35]C[24]"
    Range("A40:D40").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("B41").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-37]C[25]"
    Range("B42").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-38]C[26]"
    Range("B43").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-39]C[27]"
    Range("B45").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-41]C[28]"
    Range("B47").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-43]C[29]"
    Range("B48").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Range("C19").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-15]C[30]"
    Range("C20").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-16]C[31]"
    Range("C21").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-17]C[32]"
    Range("C22").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-18]C[33]"
    Range("C23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-19]C[34]"
    Range("C24").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-20]C[35]"
    Range("C25").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-21]C[36]"
    Range("C26").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-22]C[37]"
    Range("C27").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-23]C[38]"
    Range("C28").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-24]C[39]"
    Range("C30").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-26]C[40]"
    Range("C31").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-27]C[41]"
    Range("C32").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-28]C[42]"
    Range("C33").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-29]C[43]"
    Range("C34").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-30]C[44]"
    Range("C35").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-31]C[45]"
    Range("C36").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-32]C[46]"
    Range("C37").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-33]C[47]"
    Range("C38").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-34]C[48]"
    Range("C39").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-35]C[49]"
    Range("A40:D40").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=15
    Range("C41").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-37]C[50]"
    Range("C42").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-38]C[51]"
    Range("C43").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-39]C[52]"
    Range("C45").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-41]C[53]"
    Range("C47").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-43]C[54]"
    Range("C48").Select
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("A13").Value


End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Lucy, what is your question? Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

and also read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, have updated the original post

Comment: Hello Lucy, looks that your Macro is recorded, what you are asking for is that someone modify the macro for you. Do you have any idea how to modify your macro? I don´t think someone can do your job for free.

Answer (score 0):

You requirement is very much unclear and we don't even know how your 'Summery' sheet looks like (Perhaps a typo there). So I am writing this piece of code to give you an idea of how you can achieve this. Just change the references to the 'summery' sheet according to your requirement or make them dynamic.

```
Sub do_random()
last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summery").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To last_row

   Sheets("Master").Select
   Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Sheets(2)
   Range("A13").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-9]C[1]"
   Range("A15").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-11]C[2]"
   Range("E13").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Summery!R[-9]C[-1]"
   ....
   'Do what ever you want in here.

Next i
End Sub
```